# Escape | character in vsCode launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm trying to run my springboot app on vsCode in WSL2. Here is my launch.json:

```json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "myApp.Application",
            "projectName": "myApp",
            "args": "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local spring-boot:run",
            "linux": {
                "vmArgs": [
                    "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1|localhost|somemore",
                    "-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy",
                    "-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080",
                    "-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy",
                    "-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080",
            ]},
            "env": {
                "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE" : "local",
            }
        }
    ]
```

When I try to run the application it fails because `|` in `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts` is not properly escaped and WSL2 (Ubuntu) sees it as a shell pipeline.

How can I escape the `|` properly?

Comment: this just fixe in the VSC Insiders release

Comment: Thanks that works. When will this be implemented in a stable release?

Comment: maybe end of the month in v1.67